# SQL return a default value if a row is not found [PostgreSQL]

Tags: sql, return, row, default, default-value

I'm wondering if it was doable (in one query if possible) to make the query return a default value if a row is missing ? For example takes these 2 tables and given my query takes 2 parameter (place_id and user_id)

```
T1
place_id / tag_id
1            2
1            3
1            4
2            4
3            2
4            5

T2
user_id / tag_id / count
100         2        1
100         3        20
200         4        30
200         2         2
300         5        22
```

As you see, the pair user/tag (100,4) is missing. What I would like to archive is a query that will return me these 3 results

```
tag_id / count
2           1
3           20
4           0
```

I know that i can do this with something like this but it doesn't really match the final result as it only works if i know in advance the tag_id... and obviously only return 1 row..:

```
SELECT T1.tag_id, T2.count 
from T1 t1 
    left join T2 t2 on t1.tagId=t2.tag_id 
where t1.place_id=1 
UNION ALL 
select tag_id,0 
from T1 
where not exist (select 1 from T2 where user_id=100 and tag_id=4) 
  and tag_id=4;
```

**EDIT:** My question was not complete and had missing cases
here is an example (curtesy of @a_horse_with_no_name) http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/67042/4

Thank you!

Comment: The row with `tag_id = 4` **will** be returned by the outer join. All you need is to use `coalesce()` to convert the `null` value into a `0` See here for an example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/ed7bf/1

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name can we join tables on columns that are not foreign/primary keys ?

Comment: You can join tables on any column with matching data types.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thank you! I think this does the trick! (btw i need to also add "and t2.user_id=100"; because you can have something like this in T2 also (200,4,50) (an other user linked to the tag 4)

Answer (score 1):

The outer join will already take care of what you want.

As `t1` is the "left table" of the join, all rows from `t1` will be returned. Columns from the "right table" (`t2` in your example) will then have a `null` value. So you only need to convert that `null` to a `0`:

```
select t1.tag_id, coalesce(t2.cnt, 0)
from T1 t1 
    left join T2 t2 on t1.tag_Id=t2.tag_id 
and t1.place_id = 1;
```

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/ed7bf/1

---

Unrelated but:

Using `count` as a column name is a really bad idea, because it will require you to always enclose the column name in double quotes: `t2."count"` because it is a reserved word. Plus it doesn't really document the purpose of the column. You should find a better name for that.

Comment: About the column name, the table in my question is made up and typed on the fly. I have been trying this query on my tables and i realised that it does not exactly return the result I wanted. Look and this example. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/67042/4 (i have added other tag and users)

Comment: @Johny19: please edit your question and include the expected output based on your SQLFiddle (include the link to the SQLFiddle in your question).